# Parsing BReps from a STEP file

Tags: python, opencascade

I have a STEP file I exported from OnShape.

In my OnShape document, I have an assembly that contains a part and two instance of another assembly (*which have 2 other parts in it*).

When I open this file in *python-occ*, the only thing I get is one shape that seems to contain every faces instead of having a sort of hierarchy.

Is there a way to explore this hierarchy? Have a list of parts and where they're used inside the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution, even if I don't get any hierarchy with the assembly, I can get back all the parts and extract all the unique ones.

Open the STEP file:

```
sr = STEPControl_Reader()
sr.ReadFile("myFile.step")
```

Transfer all the roots and then for each shape as the root, visit them with:

```
ex = TopExp_Explorer(shape, TopAbs_SOLID)
```

And you can identify a unique part with the TShape:

```
solid = ex.Current()
tshapePtr = solid.TShape().DumpToString()
```

The value of **tshapePtr** will be identical with every shape using the same TShape, therefore the same part.

Then simply to extract the faces and vertices by exploring the shape per face using a triangulation.